# Prove that $AG+GB+GH+DH+HE\ge CF.$

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry, geometric-inequalities

In the diagram, $ABCDEF$ is a hexagon with $AB=BC=CD$ and $DE=EF=FA$. Angles $BCD$ and $EFA$ both equal $60°$. $G$ and $H$ are two points taken from inside the hexagon such that angles $AGB$ and $DHE$ both equal $120°$. Prove that $AG+GB+GH+DH+HE\ge CF.$

[image]

I tried to construct equilateral triangles by using the angle bisector of the two $120°$ angles, but still could not link anything to the conclusion. I also know that the conclusion is equivalent to $AB+GH+DE\ge CF$ by Triangle Inequality. Please advise.

Comment: What is the source of this problem? (If it's a textbook exercise, then what topics were covered in the chapter. If it's a contest or online challenge, then what is the intended audience? etc) This can give a sense of how elaborate a solution is expected to be.

Comment: Someone sent it to me and the solution is meant to be about Junior Math olympiad level (In AOPS, about level 5-6)

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h60438p365186

Answer (score 1):

$|AB| = |BD|,\ |DE|=|AE|$ Hence we have $$ \Delta ABG \sim \Delta
 DBG',\ \Delta DHE \sim \Delta AH'E$$ s.t. $|GH|=|G'H'|$

And we have $G'',\ H''$ s.t. $$
 \Delta BDG' \sim \Delta CDG'',\ \Delta
    AEH' \sim\Delta AFH''$$

Hence clearly $$|CG''| + |G''G'|+|G'H'| + |H'H''| + |H'' F|\geq |CF|$$